# Не получается поместить элементы в массив

Tags: java, массивы, for

Задача заключается в том, чтобы создать массив из чисел, размер которого равен умножению N на X. Например: 2 * 5 = 10 >>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

Далее нужно отсортировать числа так, чтобы массив вывел лишь те числа, которые делятся на N. Например, в этом случае: {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}.

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы поместить в массив результат. Если создавать новый массив - нужен изначальный размер, который я узнаю лишь после второго фора. Пожалуйста, подскажите и помогите, никак не могу разобраться:(((

Прикрепляю код снизу. Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 2;
    int x = 5;
    int mult = n * x;
    int[] array = new int[mult];



    for (int i = 0; i < mult; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));


    for (int j = 0;j < array.length; j++){
        if (j%n==0){
            int q = j;

            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: Можно собрать числа в ArrayList, потом выгрузить в массив

Comment: Можно при заполнении массива сразу посчитать количество чисел которые делятся на N, т.е. размер результирующего массива. Если не хотите пользоваться динамическим массивом `ArrayList`.

Comment: `Далее нужно отсортировать числа так, чтобы массив вывел лишь те числа, которые делятся на N` Это не сортировка, а фильтрация.  Создавать массив из N*x чисел, чтобы потом оставить только кратные N -- излишне, можно сразу сгенерировать последовательность из `x` чисел, удовлетворяющих условию кратности.

Comment: И кстати, если длина последовательности `N * X`, то количество чисел кратных `N` будет `X`. И если эти массивы больше нигде не нужны - можно вообще обойтись без массивов - сразу генерировать итоговую последовательность и выводить в консоль. Кажется я повторил за NowhereMan немного другими словами. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути задача сводится к тому, чтобы получить `X` чисел, кратных `N`, то есть, последовательность `N, N*2, N*3,.. N*X` и её можно решить многими способами.

Для начала следует представить решение в виде функции, принимающей два аргумента, и возвращающей *результат* в виде массива.

- Вариант 1. Цикл.
  Создаётся массив из `X` чисел, который заполняется в цикле числами, кратными `N`:

```java
// 1.1 умножение
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    int[] res = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x;) {
        res[i] = ++i * n;
    }
    return res;
}

// 1.2 сложение
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    int[] res = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0, v = n; i < x; i++, v += n) {
        res[i] = v;
    }
    return res;
}
```

- Вариант 2. `Arrays::setAll`.
  Для заполнения массивов значениями, которые зависят от индекса, можно использовать метод [`Arrays::setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-), для которого следует определить функцию-генератор значений:

```java
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    int[] res = new int[x];

    Arrays.setAll(res, i -> ++i * n); // i - индексы в диапазоне [0, x - 1]

    return res;
}
```

- Вариант 3. Stream API
  В данном случае в функциональном стиле определяется нужная последовательность чисел при помощи различных методов `IntStream`, которая трансформируется в массив.

`IntStream.iterate`

```java
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    return IntStream.iterate(n, i -> i + n) // последовательность n, n * 2,...
        .limit(x)   // взять X элементов
        .toArray(); // преобразовать в массив
}
```

`IntStream.rangeClosed`

```java
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x) // посл-ть "индексов" в диапазоне [1, X]
        .map(i -> i * n) // домножить на N каждый "индекс"
        .toArray();      // и преобразовать в массив
}
```

---

Если всё-таки нужно удалять элементы из какого-то промежуточного "массива", то лучше сгенерировать *динамический массив* или *список* значений от 1 до `N*X` (`List<Integer>`), а потом либо отфильтровать его, либо удалить ненужные значения непосредственно.

````java
```java
public static int[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x * n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list); // вывод всех промежуточных значений

    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> i % n == 0) // оставить кратные числа
            .mapToInt(i -> i)        // IntStream
            .toArray();              // получить массив
}
````

Результат - `Integer[]`

```java
public static Integer[] getXmultiplesOfN(int x, int n) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x * n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);        // вывод всех промежуточных значений
    list.removeIf(i -> i % n != 0);  // удалить некратные числа
    return list.toArray(new Integer[0]);  // преобразовать в массив
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет стримов? Данная задача с помощью StreamApi решается за 3 секунды:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] result = generate(2, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static int[] generate(int n, int x) {
        return IntStream.iterate(n, i -> i + n).limit(x).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я даже не думал, что так можно:) Но нужно было петлями сделать.

Comment: @ТудыСюды можно с джавы версии 8 и выше, раньше нельзя было)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать коллекции, к примеру.

Если тебе предпочтительнее решить через обычные массивы, то я придумал только такое решение:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 2;
    int x = 5;
    int mult = n * x;
    int[] array = new int[mult];

    for (int i = 0; i < mult; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0;j < array.length; j++){
        if (j%n==0){
            System.out.println(j);

            array[count] = j;
            count++;
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[count];

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        result[index] = array[index];
    }
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Немного подправил, так как выписало, условно, {0,2,4,6,8} вместо {2,4,6,8,10}.